# When formatting code using Ctrl+Alt+L, how to make the text inside the tags hyphenated?

Tags: html, formatting, phpstorm, webstorm

Right now I have the view:

```html
<div>
    <a>Справка после приёма</a>
    <a>Направление на R-графию</a>
    <a>ТАЛОН на ВИЧ/RW</a>
</div>
```

And I want it to become:

```html
<div>
    <a>
        Справка после приёма
    </a>
    <a>
        Направление на R-графию
    </a>
    <a>
        ТАЛОН на ВИЧ/RW
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I set it in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no settings for this; please vote for [WEB-310](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-310/HTML-Formatter-add-option-to-insert-newlines-after-opening-before-closing-tags) to be notified on any progress with this feature request

Comment: Ow... Thank you.. But... May be u know some plugin for this?..

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any:(